# Replace a word from database with a new one

Tags: javascript, php, str-replace

I am new in programming, so here is my task. I have this sentence

> I am #example and I am #example years old.

This comes from database and I need everywhere that I have #example to replace it with a dropdown button.

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: php: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=php+string+replace javascript: https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=off&q=javascript+string+replace sql: https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=off&q=sql+string+replace&oq=sql+string+replace

Answer (score -1):

Use one of these functions:

[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) 
example code:

```
$convertedString= preg_replace('/#example/', $stringOfDRopdown, $stringFromDB);
```

[str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) 
example code:

```
$convertedString= str_replace('#example', $stringFromDB, $stringOfDRopdown);
```

[strtr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) 
example code:

```
$convertedString= strtr($stringFromDB, '#example', $stringOfDRopdown);
```